# Should I put details in the scope and limitations if it is already mentioned in the objectives?

Tags: publications, writing-style, introduction

Should I put details in the scope and limitations if it is already mentioned in the objectives?

For example, we have already mentioned that we will be analyzing trends in the data. Should we also mention that as the scope of the study?

Comment: Check your question title to see if there is any typo.

Comment: Is there some reason _not_ to do so? And, what sort of "details"?